# how to scrape json api in scrapy

Tags: python, json, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to scrape an API using scrapy. i have tried various ways and couldnt do it but i have succefully returned the api as json in anaconda ! but cant seems to figure out how to parse it !

json code looks like this :

```
[
{
  "id": "6975526564553428229",
  "secretID": "6975526564553428229",
  "text": "I did a thing  Pre-order link in my bio!! #WillTheBook",
  "createTime": 1624116353,
  "authorMeta": {
  "id": "6727327145951183878",
  "secUid": "MS4wLjABAAAA8ezUaW4ecJX222ObGXxt07F9BIh4QH3-g1P1DHyChT2LLi2cn-vAE2R53- 
  H672ZO",
  "name": "willsmith",
  "nickName": "Will Smith",
  "verified": true,
  "signature": "Same kid from West Philly.",
  "avatar": "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/musically-maliva- 
  obj/1646315618666501~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1624215600&x- 
  signature=JWCnkyJ1Lq7G6K3W32nSB4NKc%2Fk%3D",
  "following": 24,
  "fans": 55900000,
  "heart": 340900000,
  "video": 81,
  "digg": 88
  },
```

what i did is after looking into some tutorials is :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import scrapy
import json
from pprint import pprint
from ..items import TiktokscrapyItem
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime

def send_request():
   response = requests.get(
       url="https://app.scrapingbee.com/api/v1/store/tiktok/user-feed",
       params={
        "api_key": "api key hiudden",
        "username": "willsmith",
    },

)
print('Response HTTP Status Code: ', response.status_code)
print('Response HTTP Response Body: ', response.content)
send_request()

class tiktokSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'tiktok'
   allowed_domains = ['app.scrapingbee.com']
   custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 10}
   custom_settings = {'FEEDS':{'poststoday.csv':{'format':'csv'}}}


def parse(self, response):
     authorMeta = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
     print(authorMeta)
     
     #main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
   process = CrawlerProcess()
   process.crawl(tiktokSpider)
   process.start()
```

dont know what to do i am trying to scrape only the text and createtime and nickname :/ but cant figure it out! any tips?

Comment: Try `print(response.json()[0]["authorMeta"])`

Comment: You don't need to "scrape" a json response from an API, that's the whole point.  Just consume the json object and take what you want.

Comment: i have tried what you suggested but still not working :/

Comment: What error do you get when you try?

Comment: Note: You're never actually calling the parse function

Comment: how to call it i watched like 15 youtube videos and im replicating what they r doing and not working for me :/ i just get the 2021-06-20 02:11:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) and i can see the json code above it !